# global variable not correctly retrieve from other module

Tags: python, import, global-variables

I am using the following code :

*main.py*

```
from global_var import var, init_var, print_var

init_var()
print(var)
print_var()
```

*global_var.py*

```
var = 0


def init_var():
    global var
    var = 1


def print_var():
    print(var)
```

The script prints the following output:

```
0
1
```

I don't understand why it does not print the following output:

```
1
1
```

I don't understand why the global variable "var" is not correctly updated when printed in main.py ?
I think the way I include the "var" from global_var.py to main.py is incorrect, but I don't see where is the issue.

Furthermore, I want to be able to modify var from withing main.py.

Comment: You can print their `id` and notice that the modified `id` has changed.

Comment: yes, it seems that it is copied instead of being passed by reference from module to module

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by modifying your code

global_var.py

```
var = 0


def init_var():
    global var
    var = 1
    return var


def print_var():
    print(var)
```

main.py

```
from global_var import  init_var, print_var


print(init_var())
print_var()
```

Comment: My problem is that I want to be enabled to modify var from within main.py. Your answer does not solve this issue

Comment: Then you could provide a variable as a parameter like ```def print_var(item):``` and then ```print(item)```. And in main.py, before the ```print_var()``` function, you could import ```var ``` and set it, ex : ```var=2``` and then pass ```var``` as a parameter in ```print_var()``` like this: ```print_var(var)```